# Did Dan Weiss and David Benioff ever say "I don't want to [make more episodes in season 8]" in an interview?

Tags: game-of-thrones

So, I was watching [a parody video on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAhKOV3nImQ) (mockup pitch meeting of season 8 of *Game of Thrones*) and there are lines they use in the video, like:

> [Danny, kind of forgot about Euron...](https://youtu.be/jAhKOV3nImQ?t=169)

which is a [real thing that one of the showrunners said](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahoHDU0T44I).

There's [another line in the video](https://youtu.be/jAhKOV3nImQ?t=412) that says:

> I don't want to [make more episodes]

Is that a real quote the showrunners said in an interview somewhere?

Comment: I think it might be a reference to the quote in this question here: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/101014/why-did-the-game-of-thrones-writers-have-so-much-influence-over-how-fast-the-sho

Answer (score 6):

## Kinda.

In an [interview](https://ew.com/tv/2019/04/09/game-of-thrones-season-8-showrunners-interview/) with Entertainment Weekly Benioff said this:

> BENIOFF: HBO would have been happy for the show to keep going, to have
> more episodes in the final season. We always believed it was about 73
> hours, and it will be roughly that. As much as they wanted more, they
> understood that this is where the story ends.

So, the wording is a bit different but the message is virtually the same.

Comment: HBO wanted to milk it, thankfully it didn't happen that way and we have a conclusion.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths D&D want to go work on their childhood dream: Star Wars. (perhaps more green too, though I don't have the numbers to substantiate that) That's also [why it took so long](https://www.vulture.com/2019/02/hbos-confederate-delay-reportedly-not-due-to-controversy.html) for season 8 to be released in the first place.